# Как получить новое значение из таблицы после UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Сразу после оператора UPDATE следует оператор SELECT, который по задумке должен выбрать новое значения обновленной ячейки. Однако возвращается старое значение. Как решить это средствами MySQL.

```
if($q = mysql_query("UPDATE `table-1` 
      SET `cell-1` = '1', 
             `last_load` = IF(`last_load` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                                       DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY), 
                                       IF(`last_load` < CURDATE(), 
                                              DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY),
                                              DATE_ADD(`last_load`, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
                                        )
                              ) WHERE `column_id` = '$column_id'")) 
{
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT `last_load` FROM `table-1` WHERE `column_id` = '$column_id'");
  send(true,mysql_fetch_assoc($q)['last_load']);
}
```

Comment: вы уверены в том что значение обновляется ?

Comment: Сервер MySQL один или речь идет об нескольких связанных репликацией?

Comment: Нет. Только MySQL. Как показано в коде, пишу в  таблицу, и хочу после вычислений и обновления строки, получить из нее же новое значение которое туда должно записаться. Если обновляю страницу то вижу, что все обновляется корректно. Есть подозрение на очередь выполнения запросов. Т.е. получаю результат селекта раньше чем осуществляется обновление строки.

Comment: нет в php никакой очереди. select обязан вернуть обновленные данные. Поищите ошибку где нибудь в другом месте. например этот send не посылает ничего или посылает, но браузер не получает. перед send запишите в какой нибудь файл инфу что были в этом месте когда и что при этом вернулось из селекта

Comment: Мистер Mike))) Читайте пж внимательно. Я же написал, что возвращается значение которое находится в таблице до ее обновления. Разумеется в php нет никаких очередей, очередь (стек) запросов формируется в MySQL, какие то выполняются мгновенно, какие то нет. И это я прекрасно понимаю. Php это только язык реализации скрипта. Здесь приведена только последовательность выполнения операций в php (шаблон). И непосредственно этот код естественно ничего не вернет. В целом код рабочий, за исключением описанной проблемы.

Comment: А что будет если написать: mysql_query("UPDATE `table-1` 
      SET `cell-1` = '1', 
             `last_load` = IF(`last_load` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                                       DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY), 
                                       IF(`last_load` < CURDATE(), 
                                              DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY),
                                              DATE_ADD(`last_load`, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
                                        )
                              ) WHERE `column_id` = '$column_id'") or die(mysql_error())

Comment: @LuckyMen MySQL в пределах одной сессии _не может_ менять порядок выполнения. поэтому проблема _обязана_ быть в другом месте. Выполните те же запросы в консоли MySQL думаю он вернет верный результат

Comment: @LuckyMen Например, обратите внимание, что ваш IF не имеет никакого смысла, ибо согласно документации http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php  mysql_query вернет FALSE только в случае ошибки в запросе. Если запрос правильный то вернется TRUE вне зависимости от того, была изменена хоть одна строка или нет. Для проверки что update прошел в той же документации рекомендуют использовать mysql_affected_rows()

Comment: Mike, спасибо. Вы действительно правы. Тут выполняется все верно. Ошибка была в самой логике исполнения программы.